# междупотоковая ошибка доступа к WPF-элементам формы из обработчика изменения *многопоточной* коллекции `volatile ObservableCollection<T1>`

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, devexpress

Делаю относительно простое многопоточное приложение, где взаимодействие между основным и вспомогательным потоками происходит через изменение значений элементов *многопоточной*коллекции;
Суть вопроса в заголовке, т.е. доступ непосредственно к *многопоточной* коллекции `volatile ObservableCollection<Status>` (являющейся одним из полей потокобезопасного экземпляра класса)  и её элементам происходит успешно из другого потока (с вызовом обработчика изменений), значения элементов ожидаемо успешно меняются, НО при попытке из обработчика изменений этой коллекции обратиться к элементам формы главного окна приложения вызывается исключение "Поток не может получить доступ к объекту, т.к. он принадлежит другому потоку".
Для наглядности привожу соотв. фрагменты кода -- основной поток программы:

```
public class DataSource //класс источника данных
{public volatile ObservableCollection<Status> Statuses;// *многопоточный* общедоступный список неких статусов
 //...
}

public partial class MainWindow : DXWindow//главное окно приложения
{
    public volatile DataSource dataSource;// *многопоточный* экземпляр источника данных (наверно, дополнительно объявлять каждое его поле тоже потокобезопасным излишне, это ничего не меняет)

    public MainWindow()
    {   DevExpress.Xpf.Core.DXGridDataController.DisableThreadingProblemsDetection = true;//!подавить исключение обнаружения между-потоковых операций (по-умолчанию DevExpress их отслеживает и не разрешает, но тут всё в наших руках)
        InitializeComponent();
        //...
        dataSource = new DataSource(oracleConnect, null);
        dataSource.Statuses.CollectionChanged += StatusesOnCollectionChanged;//присоединяем обработчик события изменения элементов коллекции
        DataContext = dataSource;//передаём фреймворку DevExpress
    }

    //обработчик события изменения коллекции
    private void StatusesOnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        switch (eventArgs.Action)
        {
            //...
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move://замена элементов
                if(eventArgs.NewItems != null)
                {
                    foreach (Status newItem in eventArgs.NewItems)
                    {
                        BarStaticItemLink itemLink_sensor_ok = (BarStaticItemLink)mainWindow.controllersStatus.FindName(newItem.code);//!ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ: Вызывающий поток(слушающий порты) не может получить доступ к объекту(элементу формы главн.окна), т.к. он принадлежит другому потоку (основному потоку приложения)
                        //...что-то с найденным сделали бы
                    };
                };
                break;
            //...
        };
    }
```

и где-то в глубине вспомогательного потока вызывается метод успешно изменяющий *многопоточную* коллекцию состояний сенсоров:

```
private void paintSensor(string sensorName, string sensorState)
        {
            Status status = dataSource.Statuses.FirstOrDefault<Status>(s => (s.code.Equals(sensorName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));//найдём интересующий нас элемент
            int statusIndex = dataSource.Statuses.IndexOf(status);//и его положение в коллекции
            if (status != null)//такой элемент существует
            {
                if (sensorState != null) //если состояние сенсора определено
                {//всё хорошо
                    status.value = Convert.ToDecimal(sensorState);
                }
                else
                {//какие-то проблемы 
                    status.value = 0;
                };

                dataSource.Statuses.Move(statusIndex, statusIndex);//костыльно =) инициируем событие изменения содержимого коллекции
            };
        }
```

Вопросы:
1)это неожиданное/неправильное поведение *многопоточной* коллекции? и почему?
2)было ли бы тоже при привязке данных?
**3)ГЛАВНОЕ - подскажите, как с этим бороться?** чтобы обработчик изменения *многопоточной* коллекции мог обращаться к элементам формы.

Comment: @АндрейNOP  хмм, спс посмотрю, но у меня то элементы коллекции успешно меняются, а вот обработчик события с чего-то вдруг стал работать из вспомогательного потока, судя по результатам  =(

Comment: Верните его в нужный поток с помощью диспетчера, как написано в том вопросе, на который я дал ссылку

Comment: почему вы называете коллекцию `volatile ObservableCollection<Status>` потокобезопасной?

Comment: @tym32167 да, не совсем подходящее прилагательное :) но *летучая* было бы ещё хуже

Comment: Я к тому, что `ObservableCollection` не является потокобезопасной коллекцией

Comment: @tym32167 да, я понял вас, так стоит говорить только о Concurrent__.